# What should be the proper use of etched?

Tags: word-usage

> His impressionable mind was etched with its horrors.

The definition states:

> 1. imprinted vividly on someone's mind or memory

It should be:

> Horrors was imprinted vividly on his mind.

Can someone explain to me if it's wrong?

Comment: We usually say that the memories were etched into the mind rather than that the mind was etched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say "should be", as they're just two different ways of saying the same thing.

Your sentence is correct, except for the fact that "horrors" is plural, so you should use the plural "were" instead of the singular "was".

> Horrors **were** imprinted vividly on his mind.